# What happen to methods with the same name during implementation?

Tags: typescript, methods, implementation, mixins

Just a simple question. If I have 2 class with 2 methods with the same name...what happen if I want to implement these 2 classes (in one new class) when I call "applyMixins"?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? What happened? Share your code

Comment: The TypeScript compiler outputs (somewhat) readable JavaScript - you can find this out for yourself if you open the output file.

Answer (score 0):

```
   class First{
       name: string;
       methodA(name: string){
           this.name= name;
       }
   }

   class Second{
        id: string;
        methodA(id: string){
           this.id= id;
       }
   }

   class newClass implements First, Second {
       id: string;
       name: string;
       methodA:()=> void;
   }
   applyMixins(newClass, [First, Second]);
   function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
       baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
           Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
               derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
           });
       });
   }
   var Pluto = new newClass();

   console.log(Pluto.methodA);
```

This is my code (just an example to see what happens...). The results in my consol log is a function wrote like a method of the SECOND CLASS. Is that correct? thanks